# Route entry condition in C++

Tags: c++, routes, multicast, omnet++

I am using omnet++ to change a specific route entry for a multicast group address. Usually, a multicast route entry is added by using the best (shortest) route to the source of the message.

However what I need to do is to modify this behavior for a specific multicast address so that it does not take the shortest path to source condition but instead uses "first entry".

What I mean is that, if after flooding the multicast packet (with no multicast route entry before) received on a router via three interfaces with the time of arrival like this: 1.eth0 2.eth1 3.eth2, it automatically sets interface eth0 as the RPF and does not compute whether this is the best path.

The normal behavior was already coded into omnett but when I found the functions to add new routes I do not understand where are the conditions of adding a new route.

[internalAddMulticastRoute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OHAH.png)

[AddMulticastRoute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFDhU.png)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, the methods you posted don't actually check anything with regards to which interface is used: whenever a multicast route is added, it is simply stored and used. You might want to have a look at where `addMulicastRoute` is called; there might be code there that controls priorities. The code in `internalAddMulticastRoute` only organizes the routing table (which is kept sorted through `upper_bound`). If you want to control which interface is used, you'll need to modify the routing table entries. I'd recommend performing a check before calling `addMulticastRoute`.

Comment: I think I found the right one ? This in PIMDM.cc creates the new route:
https://image.prntscr.com/image/YwhBxpDpRnqCAZCgmYINow.png

however it only creates one if none exists ? but it does not check RPF right away correct ? so if a multicast packet with shorter path to source comes on other interface it should change the RPF int to that one, correct ?
https://image.prntscr.com/image/ckEIO1XWRCS1jEgVjcUOlw.png

Comment: I'm not really sure. Their might be other code calling the `addMulticastRoute` method. The images you post don't really help, since they only contain irrelevant code fragments. Did you look at the documentation of the library and/or the standard it implements?